# DateAddWorkdays giving inconsistent results

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I am using the DateAddWorkdays in my access database that has a SQL backend which works great, most of the time.  But I am having some odd inconsistencies and I am not sure why.  I have stepped through the script for the past few hours and can't see where the issue is coming from.
I have a table of dates that includes 25th October 2021 as a holiday:
[image]

I am using HolidayDate field.
I call the function with

```
Me.ProductionDate = DateAddWorkdays(-Me.Lag, Me.DelDate)
```

The number is a negative as I need to count back the number of lag days to know when to start producing the items in time for the delivery date (me.DelDate).
As below, if there are only 2 days it counts back perfectly to 21st October as it removes the 25th being the holiday and the 23rd & 24th as they are weekend days.  But if the Lag is 6 days it misses a day somewhere and returns the 18th where I would expect it should return the previous friday the 15th (to test this theory, if I change the delivery date to 27th October it also returns the 18th as a result)

[image]

As much as I stepped through the script, I don't fully understand what it is doing so I am hoping someone is able to show me why I am getting this inconsistency.
I have been fiddling around with some date formatting as that was causing issues elsewhere but this script seems to have that incorporated.

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
    
Public Function DateAddWorkdays( _
    ByVal lngNumber As Long, _
    ByVal datDate As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booWorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Date

'   Adds lngNumber of workdays to datDate.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' Calendar days per week.
    Const clngWeekdayCount  As Long = 7
    ' Workdays per week.
    Const clngWeekWorkdays  As Long = 5
    ' Average count of holidays per week maximum.
    Const clngWeekHolidays  As Long = 1
    ' Maximum valid date value.
    Const cdatDateRangeMax  As Date = #12/31/9999#
    ' Minimum valid date value.
    Const cdatDateRangeMin  As Date = #1/1/100#

    Dim aHolidays() As Date

    Dim lngDays     As Long
    Dim lngDiff     As Long
    Dim lngDiffMax  As Long
    Dim lngSign     As Long
    Dim datDate1    As Date
    Dim datDate2    As Date
    Dim datLimit    As Date
    Dim lngHoliday  As Long


    lngSign = Sgn(lngNumber)
    datDate2 = datDate

    If lngSign <> 0 Then
        If booWorkOnHolidays = True Then
            ' Holidays are workdays.
        Else
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between datDate and datDate + lngDiffMax.
            ' Calculate the maximum calendar days per workweek.
            lngDiffMax = lngNumber * clngWeekdayCount / (clngWeekWorkdays - clngWeekHolidays)
            ' Add one week to cover cases where a week contains multiple holidays.
            lngDiffMax = lngDiffMax + Sgn(lngDiffMax) * clngWeekdayCount
            datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngDiffMax, datDate)
            aHolidays = GetHolidays(datDate, datDate1)
        End If
        Do Until lngDays = lngNumber
            If lngSign = 1 Then
                datLimit = cdatDateRangeMax
            Else
                datLimit = cdatDateRangeMin
            End If
            If DateDiff("d", DateAdd("d", lngDiff, datDate), datLimit) = 0 Then
                ' Limit of date range has been reached.
                Exit Do
            End If

            lngDiff = lngDiff + lngSign
            datDate2 = DateAdd("d", lngDiff, datDate)
            Select Case Weekday(datDate2)
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    ' Skip weekend.
                Case Else
                    ' Check for holidays to skip.
                    ' Ignore error when using LBound and UBound on an unassigned array.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For lngHoliday = LBound(aHolidays) To UBound(aHolidays)
                        If Err.Number > 0 Then
                            ' No holidays between datDate and datDate1.
                        ElseIf DateDiff("d", datDate2, aHolidays(lngHoliday)) = 0 Then
                            ' This datDate2 hits a holiday.
                            ' Subtract one day before adding one after the loop.
                            lngDays = lngDays - lngSign
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    lngDays = lngDays + lngSign
            End Select
        Loop
    End If

    DateAddWorkdays = datDate2
    End Function

    Public Function GetHolidays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booDesc As Boolean) _
    As Date()

'   Finds the count of holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   The holidays are returned as an array of dates.
'   DAO objects are declared static to speed up repeated calls with identical date parameters.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' The table that holds the holidays.
    Const cstrTable             As String = "tblHoliday"
    ' The field of the table that holds the dates of the holidays.
    Const cstrField             As String = "HolidayDate"
    ' Constants for the arrays.
    Const clngDimRecordCount    As Long = 2
    Const clngDimFieldOne       As Long = 0

    Static dbs              As DAO.Database
    Static rst              As DAO.Recordset

    Static datDate1Last     As Date
    Static datDate2Last     As Date

    Dim adatDays()  As Date
    Dim avarDays    As Variant

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strDate1    As String
    Dim strDate2    As String
    Dim strOrder    As String
    Dim lngDays     As Long

    If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate1Last) <> 0 Or DateDiff("d", datDate2, datDate2Last) <> 0 Then
        ' datDate1 or datDate2 has changed since the last call.
        strDate1 = Format(datDate1, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strDate2 = Format(datDate2, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strOrder = Format(booDesc, "\A\s\c;\D\e\s\c")

        strSQL = "Select " & cstrField & " From " & cstrTable & " " & _
            "Where " & cstrField & " Between " & strDate1 & " And " & strDate2 & " " & _
            "Order By 1 " & strOrder

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        ' Save the current set of date parameters.
        datDate1Last = datDate1
        datDate2Last = datDate2
    End If

    lngDays = rst.RecordCount
    If lngDays = 0 Then
        ' Leave adatDays() as an unassigned array.
    Else
        ReDim adatDays(lngDays - 1)
        ' As repeated calls may happen, do a movefirst.
        rst.MoveFirst
        avarDays = rst.GetRows(lngDays)
        ' rst is now positioned at the last record.
        For lngDays = LBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount) To UBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount)
            adatDays(lngDays) = avarDays(clngDimFieldOne, lngDays)
        Next
    End If

    ' DAO objects are static.
    ' Set rst = Nothing
    ' Set dbs = Nothing

    GetHolidays = adatDays()

End Function
```

[image]

Further to my question in the comments below, I have come across another example where the calculation is inconsistent. Above is a delivery date of 11/01/2022 which is the 11th January 2022 and with a lag of 2 days it calculates correctly including the holidays from the table below.  But a lag anywhere between  9 and 14 and it seems to ignore the holidays but as long as the lag is less than 9 or more than 14 it calculates correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I ran the function with parameters of Oct 25 2021 as a holiday, Oct 26 2021 as delivery date, -6 lag. This returns Oct 15 2021. Oct 27 2021 delivery date returns Oct 18 2021. Cannot replicate issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here, where the extended range for possible holidays didn't follow the sign of the date interval, which - in your case - caused the holiday to be excluded:

```vb
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between datDate and datDate + lngDiffMax.
            ' Calculate the maximum calendar days per workweek.
            lngDiffMax = lngNumber * clngWeekdayCount / (clngWeekWorkdays - clngWeekHolidays)

            ' Add one week to cover cases where a week contains multiple holidays.
'' Missing sign.
''            lngDiffMax = lngDiffMax + clngWeekdayCount
'' Corrected to follow the sign of the date interval.
            lngDiffMax = lngDiffMax + Sgn(lngDiffMax) * clngWeekdayCount

            datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngDiffMax, datDate)
            aHolidays = GetHolidays(datDate, datDate1)
```

Now you can run this quick test:

```vb
For n = 0 To 7 : ? d, -n, DateAddWorkdays(-n, d) : Next
26-10-2021     0            26-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -1            22-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -2            21-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -3            20-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -4            19-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -5            18-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -6            15-10-2021 
26-10-2021    -7            14-10-2021
```

The function has had a make-over and is included in my project [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date) in module `DateWork.bas`. (Disclaimer: Project holds extensive code written by me).

**Extended holidays**

Increase the maximum count of possible holidays per week to the count of workdays per week minus one:

```vb
' Common constants.
    
    ' Workdays per week.
    Public Const WorkDaysPerWeek    As Long = 5
    ' Average count of holidays per week maximum.
    Public Const HolidaysPerWeek    As Long = 4 '1
```

Now your sample will run like this:

```
Lag  Production Date 
---  ---------------
  1  10-01-2022 
  2  21-12-2021 
  3  20-12-2021 
  4  17-12-2021 
  5  16-12-2021 
  6  15-12-2021 
  7  14-12-2021 
  8  13-12-2021 
  9  10-12-2021 
 10  09-12-2021 
 11  08-12-2021 
 12  07-12-2021 
 13  06-12-2021 
 14  03-12-2021 
 15  02-12-2021 
 16  01-12-2021
```

Comment: Why did the code work correctly without revision for me?

Comment: I can't tell. Is it still the case? Does the revised code work for you?

Comment: I copy/pasted code from question. I am not seeing revised code in your answer.

Comment: It's the the last`lngDiffMax` line. The faulty is commented out for reference; the corrected is inserted.

Comment: But that is already showing in the question code that I copy/pasted. I don't see any edits to question. I did my testing before you posted answer.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean.  I recognised the code but tested with an old copy of mine having that old bug - I didn't do a copy-paste as, in the posted code, I have forgotten to update the date from 2014-10-03, thus I believed they were identical. Sorry for the confusion. So, if you run the simple test, I posted above, you will receive the same results with the code you copy-pasted? You should.

Comment: Yes, it works as well. So the OP's issue is still a mystery.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this issue.  I have another example which may help identify the problem...?
I have entered dates from 23 Dec 21 to 8 Jan 22 into tblHoliday as the christmas shutdown days.  For a delivery date of 11 Jan 22 Any lag between 9 and 14 is not calculating correctly. lag of 1 to 8 works correctly.  
Could this be a date format issue?  My dates should be dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Can't tell, works here. But date values have no format. Formats are for display only.

Comment: So it isn't that it is looking for a date in tblHoliday but can't find it because it is reading the date as yyyy-dd-mm instead of yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: No, the code checks for date _values_ having no format. Post your example data and your results.

Comment: I have added some more examples to my original post @Gustav

Comment: You Holiday dates appear left-aligned, thus probably are of data type Text, not Date. Change the field to be of data type _Date_.

Comment: I thought that would crack it.  I changed my connection to native 17 so that the dates would come through to access as dates instead of text.  But it is not working on more lags now.  Del date of 11 Jan 2022 with lag of 2 days now gives 7th Jan 2022 (this was calculating correctly before)
and with 9 days lag I get 29 Dec 2021.

Comment: @Gustav , I am getting an error on 
    For HolidayId = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays) 
LBound(holidays) = <Subscript out of range>
I have had a look around but can only find specific solutions that I can't figure out how to adapt to my issue.

Comment: That happens when there are no holidays. Please use the current function found in module _DateWork_ at [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Comment: @Gustav I am using that function and am getting to understand it more.  (great learning experience) I ran the SQL and because I am using a negative for the variable I have changed the SQL to be " Between " & SqlDate2 & " And " & SqlDate1 & " which is now bringing back dates. This is now working for the October holiday as it is only one day but for the christmas break it only seems to be using the 7th January the HolidayID so all other holiday dates are not being passed.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. Of course, _all_ helper functions should be taken from the current release, and the only SQL involved does use `Between .. And`.

Comment: @Gustav, Using the most recent function from your site, if I run with Option Explicit (which I initally left out) it errors on MaxDateValue - variable not defined.  Am I missing a function/sub?
I am working with adding a positive lag for now to avoid any confusion for a negative "number" (even if using Between ... And in SQL, the first date must still be lower than the second otherwise it will return nothing)

Comment: Yes, `MaxDateValue` is from the `DateBase` module which holds all constants used in more than one function. However, `Between .. And` does _not_ care about the order of the low and high values.

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience @Gustav but I am still not able to get this sorted.  I have updated all the scripts but I still can't get it to calculate correctly.  Is there any way I can get you to look at my database and see why it's not working.  Updating to the ODBC Driver 17 has not improved anything.  I am really frustrated that I can't crack this.    Is there any way that I can get you to have a look at my database to see if you can shed some light?

Comment: Yes, if you can provide a link or download, I can check it out. Please anonymise data if possible; if not, it's not a major issue as we mostly work with confident and trusted data. _gustav(@)cactus(.)dk_

Comment: @Gustav the database has a sql backend. Can I add that to the download?

Comment: Yes, the actual data (the dates) are crucial.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnL3FmvdGB1-hYUK3wDE5nRfnZqZZQ?e=jr2NFD
for the database.  From the main menu, select Add/Edit Delivery.  The delivery date and lag are in the sub form there 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnL3FmvdGB1-hYUL08TI3Hj1ViKfuw?e=kpdoRa 
for the sql backend.  Hopefully I have done it right but please let me know if any issues accessing these.

Comment: 1: Did you try: ` Public Const HolidaysPerWeek    As Long = 4 '1`. 2: Could you please provide a couple of _Job Number_ where the date calculation seems wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did try 4, I even tried 5 but obviously that wouldn't work.
Job 20215/66 shows the dates that are incorrect for the christmas shutdown which is just over two weeks long.
202110/1 shows where I am trying to calculate for two separate holidays on the 7th Feb and 31st Jan
Both of these jobs are the last in the table

Comment: This was caused by the _SQL Server_ backend of yours, as T-SQL behaves slightly different from _Access SQL_. A `MoveLast` must be called to count records, and in SQL `Between Value1 And Value2`, Value1 must be smaller than Value2. This was not the case with your _negative lag (interval)_ to add. Module `DateWork` at [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date) has been fully updated to correct these issues.

Comment: Awesome, that's nailed it.  I am so very grateful for your help @Gustav!
I tried to buy you some coffee but I can't get my payment to go through :(

Comment: Never mind, glad you succeeded. Merry Christmas!

Comment: And to you! :-)